# How to create content version in specific content folder from Apex?

Tags: apex, contentversion, contentdocument

I'm able to create content version and content folder in salesforce files using Apex but can anyone please help me how to create content version in one of content folder .
Thanks

Comment: You'll need to show what you tried. Best thing to do is try it manually through the UI and then explore the schemaand query to see how SFDC builds the relationships